# MIPS - print a simply double array

Tags: assembly, double, mips, qtspim

I want to print a double array, this is my simply code:

```
    .data
    myarraydouble: .space 24
    newline: .asciiz "\n"
    .text
    main:

    addi $t0,$zero,0    #set counter to 0   
    li.d $f2, 1.393701  #$f2 = 1.393701
    li.d $f4, 2.393701  #$f4 = 2.393701
    li.d $f6, 3.393701  #$f6 = 3.393701
    addi $t2,$zero,0        #reset base address

    #store doubles into array
    swc1 $f2, myarraydouble($t2)
    addi $t2,$t2,8
    swc1 $f4, myarraydouble($t2)
    addi $t2,$t2,8
    swc1 $f6, myarraydouble($t2)

    #clear $t2 to 0
    addi $t2, $zero,0

    while:
    beq $t0,3, exit

    lwc1 $f8,myarraydouble($t2) #load register from RAM 

    addi $t2, $t2, 8    #base address +4

    #print current double
    li $v0,3
    mov.d $f12,$f8
    syscall

    #print new line
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,newline
    syscall
    addi $t0, $t0, 1    #counter +1

    j while

    exit:
    li $v0,10
    syscall
```

and the output is:
[image]

Anyone knows the reason why I can't print double values?
I do not understand why my double numbers are encoded like that.

Comment: You only reserved 12 bytes for 3 doubles.  You know `double` is 64-bits, right?  I didn't read through all your code to see where you actually went wrong, but I assume it's something to do with having the wrong size for double.

Comment: you're right, i just allocated 24 bytes for 3 doubles and I set the offset from 4 to 8. Anyway my output is the same

Comment: *exactly* the same numbers?  If fixing the overlap didn't change anything, then probably you're printing garbage that didn't even come from where you were trying to store them.  (IDK, again I didn't read your code.  You should single-step it in a debugger and watch register values until you get to something specific that doesn't make sense, then [edit] your question to ask about that).  You should also edit the code in the question to fix the offsets, so that doesn't distract other future readers.  There are some people that like to help debug MIPS questions more than I do.